# If $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then must $\sigma(q^k)$ be deficient?

Tags: upper-lower-bounds, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

Let $\sigma=\sigma_{1}$ denote the classical *sum of divisors*.  Denote the *abundancy index* by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

An odd perfect number $N$ is said to be given in *Eulerian form* if
$$N = q^k n^2$$
where $q$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

The question is as is in the title:

> If $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then must $\sigma(q^k)$ be deficient?

**MY ATTEMPT**

From the *trivial relationship*
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)=\sigma(q^k n^2)=\sigma(N)=2N=2 q^k n^2,$$
I could only prove that $\sigma(q^k)/2 \mid n^2 \mid N$ (since $\gcd(q^k, \sigma(q^k))=1$).  This means that $\sigma(q^k)/2$ is deficient.

I could do
$$\sigma(q^k)=\dfrac{2n^2}{\dfrac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}},$$
and then iterate to obtain
$$\sigma(\sigma(q^k))=\sigma\Bigg(\dfrac{2n^2}{\dfrac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}}\Bigg).$$
Finally,
$$I(\sigma(q^k))=\dfrac{\sigma(\sigma(q^k))}{\sigma(q^k)}=\dfrac{\sigma\Bigg(\dfrac{2n^2}{\dfrac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}}\Bigg)}{\dfrac{2n^2}{\dfrac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k}}},$$
and this is where I get stuck since I do not know how to simplify the complex fraction on the **RHS**, with the end goal of obtaining (hopefully) tight lower and upper bounds, for $I(\sigma(q^k))$.

I do know however, that the following relationship and estimate hold:
$$\dfrac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} \mid n^2$$
$$\dfrac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} \geq 3.$$

Note that, for the case of *even perfect numbers* $M = (2^p - 1)\cdot{2^{p-1}}$ (where $2^p - 1$, and therefore $p$, is prime),
$$I(\sigma(2^p - 1)) = I(2^p) = 2 - \dfrac{1}{2^p} \leq \frac{7}{4},$$
or by observing directly that $\sigma(2^p - 1) = 2^p$ is a prime power and therefore deficient.

**Update (September 29, 2020)** - As correctly observed by [mathlove](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/78967), the last inequality above should be
$$I(\sigma(2^p - 1)) = I(2^p) = 2 - \dfrac{1}{2^p} \geq \frac{7}{4}.$$

Assume that $\sigma(q^k) \equiv k+1 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ is a prime power.  This forces $\sigma(q^k)=2$.  This means $2\sigma(n^2)=2q^k n^2$, which in turn is equivalent to
$$I(n^2) = q^k < 2$$
which is a contradiction (as $q$ being the special prime it ought to satisfy $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, which means $q \geq 5$ and $k \geq 1$, and these imply that $q^k \geq 5$).  Thus, $\sigma(q^k)$ is not a prime power.

Assume that $\sigma(q^k) = u^s v^t$, where $u < v$ are primes.  Since $\sigma(q^k) \equiv k+1 \equiv 2 \pmod 4$, then this forces $u = 2$ and $s = 1$.  (Note that, WLOG, we may assume that $v \geq 3$.)  We now compute
$$I(\sigma(q^k))=\frac{3}{2}\cdot{I(v^t)}<\frac{3}{2}\cdot{\dfrac{v}{v-1}} \leq \bigg(\frac{3}{2}\bigg)^2 = \frac{9}{4},$$
whence we **cannot** conclude if $\sigma(q^k)$ is deficient or not.

*Alas, this is where I get stuck.*

Comment: Isn't $q$ a prime?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @player3236.  Yes, $q$ is the *special/Euler prime* of the odd perfect number $N$.

Comment: Got it.  Found an applicable result in the literature.  Posting an answer in a bit.

Comment: I know that, if $q=5$ and $k=1$, then $\sigma(q^k)=\sigma(q)=q+1=6$, which is *nondeficient*.

Comment: My guess is that this is a very difficult question. Not for example, that resolving your question in the affirmative would show that for example 5 cannot be the special prime, since then $\sigma(5^k)$ would  be divisible by 3. Similarly, if one could show that $\sigma(q^k)$ had to be abundant one would then rule out 13^1 as the special component. I suspect any answer to this question will be very difficult.

Comment: I noticed the following : (1) In the case of even perfect numbers, we have $\dfrac 74\color{red}{\le }I(\sigma(2^p−1))=2−\dfrac{1}{2^p}\lt 2$. (2) If $\sigma(q^k)=u^sv^t$ where $u\lt v$ are primes such that $5\le v$, then $I(\sigma(q^k))<\dfrac 32\cdot \dfrac{v}{v−1}\lt 2$, so $\sigma(q^k)$ is deficient. (3) If $\sigma(q^k)=u^s\cdot 3^t$ where $u$ is an integer (not necessarily a prime) such that $\gcd(u,3)=1$, then $\dfrac u2\ (=m)$ is odd with $s=1$, and $I(\sigma(q^k))=\dfrac 34\left(3-\dfrac{1}{3^t}\right)\cdot\dfrac{\sigma(m)}{m}\color{red}{\ge} 2$, so $\sigma(q^k)$ is not deficient.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts on this problem, @JoshuaZ!  Please go ahead and write that out as an actual answer so that I may upvote.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, @mathlove!  Please go ahead and write that out as an actual answer so that I may upvote.

Comment: I don't really think saying that the problem is likely to be very difficult counts enough as an answer that it should  be there rather than a comment.

Comment: @JoshuaZ: Good day to you, Josh!  We have recently been able to rule out ${13}^{1}$ as the special component in an odd perfect number, in this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4614690).  More specifically, we were able to prove that
$$k = 1 \implies p \not\equiv {13} \pmod {16}.$$
(Note that the argument in the linked MSE question can be easily generalized to
$$p \not\equiv {k + 12} \pmod {16}.$$
Please let me know if you have any questions.)

Comment: @JoshuaZ: My last comment is in response to your [earlier comment from September 24, 2020](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3831043/if-n-qk-n2-is-an-odd-perfect-number-with-special-prime-q-then-must-si?rq=1#comment7917939_3831043).

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris That´s great. Can you write that argument up in detail? As it is currently it is a bit hard to follow the pieces.

Comment: @JoshuaZ: Sure thing!  I will write the argument up in detail and send you an e-mail in a bit.

Comment: @JoshuaZ: Blimey, this is embarrassing, but we recently found a typo in our Theorem 3.8, for this [paper (page 15)](https://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-26/NNTDM-26-3-008-024.pdf).  The statement of Theorem 3.8 should read as follows: Suppose that $n = p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$ satisfying
$\sigma(m^2) \equiv 3 \pmod 8$. This implies that exactly one of the following conditions hold:  1. p ≡ 1 (mod 16), k ≡ 5 (mod 16), 2. p ≡ 5 (mod 16), k ≡ 9 (mod 16)
3. p ≡ 9 (mod 16), k ≡ 13 (mod 16), XOR 4. p ≡ 13 (mod 16), k ≡ 1 (mod 16).

Comment: @JoshuaZ: In other words, the start of the abstract of this [paper](https://nntdm.net/volume-26-2020/number-3/8-24/) should read as follows:  In this article, we consider the various possibilities for $p$ and $k$ modulo $16$, and show conditions under which the respective congruence classes for $\sigma(m^2)$ (modulo $8$) are attained, if $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$.  We prove that: **(1)**
$\sigma(m^2) \equiv 1 \pmod 8$ holds only if $p + k \equiv 2 \pmod {16}$.  **(2)** $\sigma(m^2) \equiv 3 \pmod 8$ holds only if $p - k \equiv {12} \pmod {16}$. (continued)

Comment: (continued) @JoshuaZ: **(3)** $\sigma(m^2) \equiv 5 \pmod 8$ holds only if $p + k \equiv {10} \pmod {16}$.  **(4)** $\sigma(m^2) \equiv 7 \pmod 8$ holds only if $p - k \equiv 4 \pmod {16}$.

Comment: @JoshuaZ:  These findings match Chen and Luo's in their 2013 article titled 
"Odd multiperfect numbers".  Fortunately, the rest of the paper is not affected.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris Ah, that is unfortunate, but not too surprising. Something about those congruences seemed off, and I'm sorry I didn't identify this earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On OP's request, I am converting my comment into an answer.

Also, I'm going to add some more thoughts at the end of this answer.

I noticed the following :

(1) In the case of even perfect numbers, we have
$$\frac 74\color{red}{\le} I(\sigma(2^p−1))=2−\frac{1}{2^p}\lt 2$$
from which we see that $\sigma(2^p−1)$ is deficient.

(2) If $\sigma(q^k)=u^sv^t$ where $u\lt v$ are primes such that $5\color{red}{\le} v$, then $I(\sigma(q^k))<\dfrac 32\cdot \dfrac{v}{v−1}\lt 2$, so $\sigma(q^k)$ is deficient.

(3) If $\sigma(q^k)=u^s\cdot 3^t$ where $u$ is an integer (not necessarily a prime) such that $\gcd(u,3)=1$, then $\dfrac u2\ (=m)$ is odd with $s=1$, and $$I(\sigma(q^k))=\dfrac{3\sigma(m)(3^{t+1}-1)}{2m\cdot 3^t\cdot 2}=\underbrace{\dfrac 34\left(3−\dfrac{1}{3^t}\right)}_{\ge 2}\cdot \underbrace{\dfrac{\sigma(m)}{m}}_{\ge 1}\ge 2$$ so $\sigma(q^k)$ is not deficient.

---

In the following, I'm going to add some more thoughts.

(4) One can prove that if $(q,k)$ satisfies either $q\equiv 2\pmod 3$ or $(q,k)\equiv (1,2)\pmod 3$, then $\sigma(q^k)$ is not deficient.

*Proof* :

If $q\equiv 2\pmod 3$, then we have
$$\sigma(q^k)=1+q+\cdots +q^k\equiv (1-1)+(1-1)+\cdots +(1-1)\equiv 0\pmod 3$$since $k$ is odd.

Also, if $(q,k)\equiv (1,2)\pmod 3$, then we have
$$\sigma(q^k)=1+q+\cdots +q^k\equiv 1+1+\cdots +1\equiv k+1\equiv 0\pmod 3$$

So, in either case, we get $\sigma(q^k)\equiv 0\pmod 3$.

Since we have $\sigma(q^k)\equiv 2\pmod 4$, there are positive integers $s,t$ such that $$\sigma(q^k)=2s\cdot 3^t$$where $s$ is odd satisfying $\gcd(s,3)=1$. Then, we have
$$I(\sigma(q^k))=\frac{3\sigma(s)(3^{t+1}-1)}{2s\cdot 3^t\cdot 2}=\underbrace{\dfrac 34\left(3−\dfrac{1}{3^t}\right)}_{\ge 2}\cdot \underbrace{\dfrac{\sigma(s)}{s}}_{\ge 1}\ge 2$$
from which we see that $\sigma(q^k)$ is not deficient.

---

So, the remaining cases are $(q,k)$ satisfying either $(q,k)\equiv (1,0)\pmod 3$ or $(q,k)\equiv (1,1)\pmod 3$.

Answer (score 0):

From the paper titled [On Odd Perfect Numbers and Even $3$-Perfect Numbers](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/a6self/a6self.pdf) by Cohen and Sorli, published in *Integers* (2012, **Theorem 3**, page 3), we have the following result:

> Let $q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$.  Then the following inequality holds unconditionally:
> $$\sigma(\sigma(q^k)) \leq 3q^k - 1.$$

This result implies that
$$I(\sigma(q^k)) \leq \dfrac{3}{I(q^k)} - \dfrac{1}{\sigma(q^k)},$$
from which it follows that
$$I(\sigma(q^k)) \leq \dfrac{3}{I(q^k)} - \dfrac{1}{\sigma(q^k)} < \dfrac{3}{I(q^k)}.$$
But we know that
$$I(q^k) \geq \dfrac{q+1}{q} \iff \dfrac{3}{I(q^k)} \leq \dfrac{3q}{q+1} < 3.$$

We therefore infer that $I(\sigma(q^k)) < 3$, from which we **cannot** conclude whether $\sigma(q^k)$ is deficient or not.