# If $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then must $\sigma(n^2)$ be abundant?

Tags: inequality, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

**Preamble:**  This post is an offshoot of this [earlier MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3831043).

The topic of [odd perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers) likely needs no introduction.

Let $\sigma=\sigma_{1}$ denote the classical *sum of divisors*.  Denote the *abundancy index* of the positive integer $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.  A positive integer $x$ satisfying $I(x) < 2$ (respectively, $I(x) > 2$) is said to be *deficient* (respectively, *abundant*).

An odd perfect number $N$ is said to be given in *Eulerian form* if
$$N = q^k n^2$$
where $q$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

The question is as is in the title:

> If $N = q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $q$, then must $\sigma(n^2)$ be abundant?

*UPDATE (September 11, 2021 - 1:56 PM Manila time)* - Finally proved that $\sigma(n^2)$ must be **deficient** in my answer below.

**MY ATTEMPT**

From the *trivial relationship*
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)=\sigma(q^k n^2)=\sigma(N)=2N=2 q^k n^2,$$
I could only prove that $\sigma(n^2)/q^k \mid n^2 \mid N$ (since $\gcd(q^k, \sigma(q^k))=1$).  This means that $\sigma(n^2)/q^k$ is deficient.

Also, I obtain
$$\sigma(\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)) = \sigma(2q^k n^2) = 3\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2).$$
Using the inequality
$$\sigma(AB) \leq \sigma(A)\sigma(B)$$
which holds for all positive integers $A, B$, we have
$$3\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2) = \sigma(\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)) \leq \sigma(\sigma(q^k))\sigma(\sigma(n^2)).$$

From the paper titled [On Odd Perfect Numbers and Even $3$-Perfect Numbers](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/a6self/a6self.pdf) by Cohen and Sorli, published in *Integers* (2012, **Theorem 3**, page 3), we have the following result:

> Let $q^k n^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $q$.  Then the following inequality holds unconditionally:
> $$\sigma(\sigma(q^k)) \leq 3q^k - 1.$$

This result implies that
$$3\bigg(\frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{q - 1}\bigg)\sigma(n^2) = 3\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2) = \sigma(\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)) \leq \sigma(\sigma(q^k))\sigma(\sigma(n^2)) \leq (3q^k - 1)\sigma(\sigma(n^2)),$$
from which we get
$$I(\sigma(n^2)) \geq 3\bigg(\frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{(q - 1)(3q^k - 1)}\bigg) = \frac{q - 3}{(q - 1)(3q^k - 1)} + \frac{q}{q - 1} := f(q,k).$$

I noticed that
$$f(5,1) = \frac{9}{7}$$
$$f(13,1) = \frac{21}{19}.$$

I did confirm (graphically, by using WolframAlpha) that it is true that
$$f(q,k) > 1.$$

**My hunch is that $\sigma(n^2)$ is *abundant*, as $\omega(n) \geq 9$ (which means $n^2$ has a lot of prime factors), as proved by [Nielsen (2015)](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/2015-84-295/S0025-5718-2015-02941-X/S0025-5718-2015-02941-X.pdf), where $\omega(n)$ is the number of *distinct* prime factors of $n$.**

*Alas, this is where I get stuck!*

**UPDATE**

Since $3q^k - 1 < 3q^k$, then
$$I(\sigma(n^2)) \geq f(q,k) = 3\bigg(\frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{(q - 1)(3q^k - 1)}\bigg) > 3\bigg(\frac{q^{k+1} - 1}{{3q^k}(q - 1)}\bigg) = I(q^k) > 1,$$
which analytically confirms my graphical observation above.

Comment: Please clarify what remains to be shown exactly to complete your proof. You seem to be already quite close.

Comment: How so, @Peter?  Note that we need to show that $I(\sigma(n^2)) > 2$ in order to prove that $\sigma(n^2)$ is *abundant*.

Comment: Finally figured it out, @Peter! Writing out a conclusive answer now in this regard.  Thank you very much for your time and attention, and for the hint!  =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $N$ be an odd perfect number given in the so-called *Eulerian form*
$$N = q^k n^2$$
where $q$ is the *special/Euler prime* satisfying $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.

From the trivial relationship
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2)=\sigma(q^k n^2)=\sigma(N)=2N=2 q^k n^2$$
we obtain
$$\bigg(\frac{\sigma(q^k)}{2}\bigg)\cdot{\sigma(n^2)}=N=q^k n^2$$
which implies that $\sigma(n^2)$ is a *proper factor* of the (odd) *perfect number* $N$ (since $\sigma(q^k)/2 \geq (q^k + 1)/2 \geq (5+1)/2 = 3$).

We therefore conclude that $\sigma(n^2)$ must be **deficient**.